creating a dispatcher of lambda functions
I'm thinking of creating a dispatcher() function for a server by specifying pairs of {ID, LAMBDA} for server to choose from. All IDs are unique. Assuming I have send() and receive() functions supporting all allowed types, how would you write a dispatcher() function that receives ID, selects corresponding lambda function, receives its parameters, invokes it and sends the result? I will have multiple instances of dispatcher() for different instances of a server each with different sets of functions and I don't want switch statements in implementation. Here is a simplified skeleton of such application (compiler explorer demo):
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
auto receive() { return -1; } // for exposition only

void send(auto&& ... values);

template<std::pair...functions>
void dispatcher()
{
    for(auto function_id = 0; function_id != -1;)
    {
        function_id = receive<int>();
        // select function corresponding to function_id
        // receive function arguments
        // invoke function and send return value
    }
}

int main()
{
    dispatcher<{100, []{ return 100;}},
    {1000, [](const std::vector<int>& v){ return v; }}>();
}


Generally this kind of runtime dispatching is handled using a std::(unordered_)map of IDs mapped to function pointers (or lambdas stored as std::function). But the functions/lambdas would need to have a common signature, unless you wrap them with std::variant or equivalent. I would not try to accomplish this using template arguments on the dispatcher.

Sounds like someone is trying to reinvent a subset of COM... A note: It's always reinvented poorly.

Are these IDs monotonically increasing ints?  (1, 2, 3, 4, ...)

@catnip -- I wouldn't want to require ordering unless necessary.

Your lambdas don't take the same arguments so the "receive function arguments" part becomes interesting. Where do they come from? How are they packaged? In a tuple of some sort? If your lambdas all accept the same type of argument, there's no problem.

Take and return some variant format (as json).

@Ted Lyngmo -- yes, lambdas can have different arguments. Of course, they can be packaged in tuples and expanded when needed.

@Gene Perhaps you should package both the receiving and sending lambdas together to not have to do two ID lookups? I made this demo for the receiver only. Does that look like what you are after?

@Ted Lyngmo -- I think fold expression like in your demo is the right way to solve it. For lambdas, a trait is needed to extract arguments, then you can wrap them in tuple.

@Gene If you tie the three parts (receiving function arguments, calling the function with those and the sending the result) together it becomes less problematic. Each lambda would then be self-contained with all three parts and no need for special handling.

@Ted Lyngmo -- do you have example? If I understand you correctly you want to have a tuple of all three, but then tuple is not a structural type.

@Gene No, I mean that you make a pair of the ID and a lambda. Inside the lambda, it  fetches its arguments, which can be special for each lambda and it calls the function with those arguments and sends the result, which can also be different for every lambda.

This solution is based on the following two steps:

First, we create a fold-expression (suggested by @Ted Lyngmo) that
results in calling executor() function corresponding to the lambda
function ID.

Second, we use lambda function traits to determine parameter types
necessary to receive those parameters, passing them to the
corresponding lambda function and sending the result of execution.


The following code demonstrates this approach (Compiler Explorer Demo):
template<class Fn> struct lambda_traits;

template< class R, class G, class ... A >
struct lambda_traits<R(G::*)(A...) const>
{
    using Args = std::tuple<std::remove_cvref_t<A>...>;
};

template<class Fn>
struct lambda_traits : lambda_traits<decltype(&Fn::operator())>{};

template<class Fn>
using lambda_args = typename lambda_traits<std::remove_cvref_t<Fn>>::Args;

template <std::pair function>
auto executor() {
    // receive function arguments for function.first here
    std::cout << "Executing function ID " << function.first << '\n';
    
    std::apply([&](auto&&...args)
    {
        (receive(args), ...);
        send(std::invoke(function.second, std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...));        
    }, lambda_args<decltype(function.second)>{});
}

template<std::pair...functions>
void dispatcher()
{
    for(auto function_id : {10, 100})
    {
        //function_id = receive<int>();
        (void)((functions.first == function_id
            &&
        (executor<functions>(), true)) || ...);
    }
}

int main()
{
    dispatcher<{100, []{ return 123;}},
    {10, [](const std::vector<int>& v){ return v; }}>();
}


You have to wrap receive<Args...>() in std::initializer_list (to initialize tuple) to have guaranteed evaluation order.

@Jarod42 -- good catch, comma operator will do that too.

@Jarod42 -- does treating rvalue references as lvalue references as long as temporary is alive violate anything in the Standard?

As I understand your question no. BTW, they have a name, there are l-values.
